# Vue.js : How persistent is the data of the state properties in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I wanted to know the lifecycle of the state properties in Vuex's store.js. If its session dependent or I need to clear all the data associated with the properties. And if so how ?

Comment: Not persistent at all. Refreshing or leaving the page will erase the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Vuex store is usually not persisted. It is handled like regular JavaScript: After the page is reloaded, the data is released.

If you want to persist the Vuex Store in a browser, there are however possibilities for that. One example is [`vuex-persistedstate`](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate). It stores all or certain keys to the localStorage of the browser and can be easily added as a Vuex plugin.

You might want to check out the official Vue.JS Chrome DevTools plugin where you can inspect the contents of the Vuex store during runtime.